# Is there a way to modify the format of a user input (ex:900 -> 9h00)?

Tags: java, time, time-format

I'm currently working with a school-made class that allow the reading of a user input.

Here is my currently code which ask the hour, then the minutes for a car reservation because I need to give the final hour in the format HHhMM:

```
 public class Facturation {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      while (true) {

    System.out.println(MSG1);
     System.out.println (MSG_SOLLICITATION1);

   while (true ) { 
       HrDebut= Clavier.lireInt();
       if (HrDebut >= 9 && HrDebut <= 18 ) {
        break;
        } else {
        System.out.println (MSG_ERREUR);
        System.out.println (MSG_SOLLICITATION1);
         } }
   System.out.println (MSG_SOLLICITATION2);
   while (true) {
       MinDebut=Clavier.lireInt();
      if (MinDebut >= 00 && MinDebut <= 59 ){
    System.out.println("CONFIRMATION:" + "\n"
   + "Debut de la location:" + HrDebut + "h" + MinDebut 
     + "\n" + "\n" + MSG_RTR_MENU) ;
      Clavier.lireFinLigne();
    break;
```

So if the user give 9+34, the final output would be: 9h34.

Is there a way to only have the user input 1 number from 900 to 1800 (9am to 18PM) and then give a final output in the format HHhMM?

For example, user input 945 -> final output is 9h45.

Thanks.

Comment: Read in `n`,  use `n / 100` to separate the HH part, `n % 100` to get the MM part.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Use scanner class for user input.

```
 Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
```

2 - ask user to input time in your desired format like 945 or 1230.

3 - then use below method logic in your code to get hour and minute.

```
public static void t() {
    int a = 1945;//suppose your time

    int minute = a%100; // your minute data
    System.out.println(minute);
    int hour = a/100;// your hour data
    System.out.println(hour);
}
```

In this code we have not taken care of wrong input. so if you are not sure that user will always provide correct data, Please implement logic for data corrections check.(like number can not be less than 3 digit or more than 4 digit. time range is 100 to 2400).

If its 1 o'clock - user need to enter 100.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

Java has a built-in class representing a time of day, `LocalTime`, and facilities for parsing a string into a `LocalTime` and formatting it back into a string. So yes, reading the time as 934 or 1800 goes nicely, and there’s no reason to hand format the way you did in the question.

```
    DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("Hmm");
    DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H'h'mm");
    LocalTime minTime = LocalTime.of(9, 0);
    LocalTime maxTime = LocalTime.of(18, 0);

    String userInput = "1800";
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(userInput, inputFormatter);
    if (time.isBefore(minTime) || time.isAfter(maxTime)) {
        System.out.println("TODO put your error message here");
    } else {
        String output = time.format(outputFormatter);
        System.out.println("Debut de la location: " + output);
    }
```

Output from the example code snippet is:

> Debut de la location: 18h00

One detail may surprise here: The input format pattern string `Hmm` would ordinarily mean input in three digits, one digit hour of day and two digit minute of the hour. However, when Java sees that there are four digits, not three, since it knows that hour of day may sometimes require two digits, it is smart enough to figure that `1800` is two-digit hour, 18, and two-digit minute, 00.

In the output format pattern, `H'h'mm`, the single quotes around the `h` means that this letter is to be printed literally, it is not a format pattern letter like `H` and `mm`.

If you can, I recommend that you read the input as a `String`, not an `int`.

If the user has typed a time that doesn’t conform with the exptected, for instance a wrong format or a minute of hour greater than 59, `LocalTime.parse` will throw a `DateTimeParseException`, so you will want to catch this exception, issue an error message and ask the user to try again.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.